# Get the first letter of subdomain as variable

Tags: nginx, subdomain, regex, conf

How do I get the first letter of a variable in nginx

example

```
        server_name ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.development\.test$;

        location / {
                root /var/www/test/$subdomain.0/$subdomain;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

So this would work
`http://apple.development.test/`
going to this path
`/var/www/test/a/apple`

I have seen methods with map but not sure how to correctly do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following approach might work too:

```
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>(?<firstletter>\w)\w+)\.development\.test$;

location / {
    root /var/www/test/$firstletter/$subdomain;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new variable with the first letter using the map module:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map

Example:

```
map $subdomain $firstletter {
    default                    "";
    "~^(?<letter>.{1}).*$"  $letter;
}
```

**Edit:** correct PCRE syntax for named capturing groups is `(?<name>regexp)`